# Connect to remotemysql.com on my website?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to connect a database on remotemysql.com too my website (ddu.nu/3/weatherstation). When i try to run the connection to the database on the website the connection fails. But when i try the exact same code on the localhsot the connection is created. Here is the code that i am using.

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("remotemysql.com:3306", "dbuser", "dbpass", "dbname");     
if(!$connect ) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
```

The website doesn't give any error.
Here is the website

[image: connection on website]

And here is the localhost

[image]

My quetion is what I need to do in order for the real website to function.

Comment: Put http:// before remotemysql.com

Comment: That doesnt work still fails to connect.

Comment: :3306 is redundant as it is default.  Try removing that

Comment: Have also tried that, but I still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you asked your hosting provider whether they _allow_ such external database connections …?

Comment: @danronmoon that's nonsense. Mysql doesn't use the HTTP protocol.

Comment: @MortenChristensen CBroe is right. Most likely your hosting provider blocks such outbound connections through their firewall. Talk to their support team about whether that is the case, and whether they will make any exceptions. Most hosting packages come with a SQL instance built-in and they normally expect you to use that instead to hold your data.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to disable ssl or the ssl have to have ssl cert, mine is work pefectly with ssl disable:

String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://remotemysql.com:3306/";

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL + dbName + "?useSSL=false",
dbUsername,
dbPassword);

Comment: Welcome! It appears as though your answer is in a programming language other than the one this question uses. Please update to use PHP

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).